# Passing Two Variables into Pipeline

Tags: f#

I have been attempting the Eulers in F#* and am currently on #5. My problem is using a function that takes more than one parameter in a pipeline operation.

This function correctly returns whether the first parameter is divisible by every member of an array which is the second parameter:

```
let isDivisibleBy seq n =
    seq
    |> Seq.forall (fun x -> n % x = 0)

isDivisibleBy [|1 .. 10|] 2520 //true
```

However, the following statement does not work:

```
Seq.initInfinite
    |> Seq.find isDivisibleBy [|1 .. 10|]
```

I get the following error:

> error FS0001: The type '((int -> 'c) -> seq<'c>) -> 'd' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

*"2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder. What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short answer:

You're missing parentheses and first argument of `Seq.initInfinite`. Correct code:

```
Seq.initInfininte id
|> Seq.find (isDivisibleBy [|1..10|])
```

---

## Explanation

In expression `Seq.find isDivisibleBy [|1 .. 10|]` you're trying to call function `Seq.find` with two arguments, `isDivisibleBy` and `[|1 .. 10|]`. And then you're trying to use the resulting value as second argument of the pipe `(|>)` operator. Your code is equivalent to this (just make each call a separate step):

```
let a = Seq.find isDivisibleBy [|1 .. 10|]
Seq.initInfinite |> a
```

Which is obviously incorrect.

From the rest of your code, I infer that what you probably wanted to do was to partially apply the function `isDivisibleBy` to argument `[|1 .. 10|]`, and then pass the resulting value to `Seq.find`, like this:

```
let b = isDivisibleBy [|1 .. 10|]
let a = Seq.find b
Seq.initInfinite |> a
```

But this still won't compile, because `Seq.initInfinite` takes one argument - a function mapping indexes to elements of generated sequence, - but you provide no arguments:

```
let b = isDivisibleBy [|1 .. 10|]
let a = Seq.find b
let c = Seq.initInfinite (fun x -> x)
c |> a
```

Removing intermediate `let`s from the above code and replacing the redundant lambda `fun x -> x` with `id`, we get the final answer:

```
Seq.initInfininte id
|> Seq.find (isDivisibleBy [|1..10|])
```

Comment: Thanks, Fyodor. Also +1 for noticing my error with initInfinite.

Comment: For finding the smallest *positive* number, you need to replace `id` with `((+) 1)`